# Nested if but Operators not picking up values

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, numeric, vba

```
Private Sub Check()

  For rwIndex = 2 To 227
    If (Len(Cells(rwIndex, 1).Value) > 0) Then
      If (Cells(rwIndex, 3).Value < 6000) Then
        Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = " Below 6M Is Not Acceptable"
      ElseIf (Cells(rwIndex, 3).Value > 6000) And  (Cells(rwIndex,3).Value < 8000) Then
        Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = " Not As Per Strategy"
      End If
      If Len(Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value) > 0 Then
        If (Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value < 0) Then
          Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Negative Growth Is Inacceptable"
        Else:
          If Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value < 15 Then
            Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Growth percent is Inappropriate"
          Else:
            If Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value < 25 Then
              Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Growth Percent is OK"
            Else:
              Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Growth percent Must be reviewed"
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next rwIndex
End Sub
```

trying this

but it stops comparing
tried many ways to make this code work 
tried ELSEIF else and nested if too... but the values just stop matching
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are testing numbers such as 0.24 (i.e. 24%) against numbers such as 15.  You probably intend to compare them to numbers such as 0.15 (i.e. 15%) and 0.25 (i.e. 25%).

```
Private Sub Check()

  For rwIndex = 2 To 227
    If Len(Cells(rwIndex, 1).Value) > 0 Then
      If Cells(rwIndex, 3).Value < 6000 Then
        Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = " Below 6M Is Not Acceptable"
      ElseIf Cells(rwIndex, 3).Value > 6000 And Cells(rwIndex,3).Value < 8000 Then
        Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = " Not As Per Strategy"
      End If
      If Len(Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value) > 0 Then
        If Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value < 0 Then
          Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Negative Growth Is Inacceptable"
        ElseIf Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value < .15 Then
          Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Growth percent is Inappropriate"
        ElseIf Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value < .25 Then
          Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Growth Percent is OK"
        Else
          Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value & "  Growth percent Must be reviewed"
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next rwIndex
End Sub
```